# How many layers in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

Is there a way to check how many layers a docker container is composed without going over each docker file that it “inherits” to count how many `RUN` are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes.

```
docker history -q <imagenameorid> | wc -l
```

This will give you the count of layer in the given image

Comment: That command shows me a line even for lines that set `ENV`. Do these also commit an image?

Comment: Yes. ENV also is a layer